# Display username instead of user_id in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

Hey i'm new on cakePHP and i'm following Bookmark tutorial, but instead of bookmark table I'm using products table,
Here what i want is while adding new product, i want to display **username** instead of **user_id** in input field user_id.

```
 <?= $this->Form->create($product) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Product') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('user_id', ['options' => $users]);
        echo $this->Form->input('title');
        echo $this->Form->input('description');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

UsersTable have

`id,
username,
email,
password`

i followed `$username = $this-Users->find('list')`
but i really don't understand how to write this query.
what query i need to run?,

Comment: Make sure you are getting `$users` using the `list` method. Also, make sure the`displayField` of Users table is `username`

Comment: thank you @yBrodsky, of course diplayField of table is username, i followed the naming conventions, now help me to figure it out, what i need to do?

Comment: show us your query to get `$users`

Comment: sir, I haven't write any query yet, i just baked the tables.

Comment: Check in your controller. That $users is comming from somewhere. Take a look at @FrankSunnyman 's answer

Comment: $users = $this->paginate($this->Users);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also do like this

**UsersTable.php**

```
 public function initialize(array $config)
    {       
         $this->displayField('username'); 
    }
```

**then the code**

```
echo $this->Form->input('user_id', ['options' => $users]);
```

will now pull up all users in the users table

Comment: good it help and that idea, is from my friend @greg smith he help me last year

Answer (score 3):

The select input takes an array with the key => value format. So to get your `$users` array in that format, in your controller you could do the following:

```
$query = $this->Users->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'id',
    'valueField' => 'username'
]);
$users = $query->toArray();
```

This would for example give you this array:

```
[
    1 => 'Javed',
    2 => 'Test user'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all it depends on your cakephp version, 
Here is the solution for the **cakephp 2.X version**

To display the username instead of id in your case, You must have to assign the list of the users data

Query would be like:

```
//In your controller action code
$users = $this->Users->find('list', array(
        'fields' => array('id', 'username')
        'recursive' => 0
));
$this->set(compact('users'));
```

This will get outputs in html

```
//In your html view side jsut have to field name not required to write options parameter cakephp auto detect that and filled up the data

<?= $this->Form->create($product) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Product') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('user_id', ['empty' => __('Select username')]);
        echo $this->Form->input('title');
        echo $this->Form->input('description');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

If you are using another version than no worries please add comment your version will help you to resolved on your version also

Hope this will help you

Thanks